# WP_Query can't exclude more than 1 author?

Tags: wp-query

It seem wp_query have the problem where it does not accept more than 1 negative value in author argument. for example:

```
$args = array('author=-2,-3,-4'); 
$newquery = WP_Query($args);
```

This grab everything else. Simply doesn't work.

I found this [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16854), but seem still no official patch for this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is not possible to pass an array with author IDs to exclude them. The reason is in `wp-includes/query.php` at [line 2294 - 2298](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2294)

```
if ( strpos($q['author'], '-') !== false ) {
  $eq = '!=';
  $andor = 'AND';
  $q['author'] = explode('-', $q['author']);
  $q['author'] = (string)absint($q['author'][1]); // this line select the first ID and only this ID
} else {
  $eq = '=';
  $andor = 'OR';
  }
```

You have to get all author IDs, then exclude the unwanted authors and request the posts from the remaining authors

```
// array for user IDs
$users   = array();

// roles to include
$roles   = array( 'author', 'editor', 'contributor', 'administrator', 'superadmin' );

// user IDs to exclude
$exclude = array( 2,3,5 );

// get all users
$_users = get_users();

foreach ( $_users as $user ) {

    // do not add the user ID if the users role does not match or the users ID is excluded
    if ( in_array( $user->ID, $exclude ) || ! in_array( $user->roles[0], $roles ) )
        continue;

    // add user
    array_push( $users, $user->ID );

}

$args = array('author=' . implode( ',', $users ); 
$newquery = WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [WordPress version 3.7](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.7) (released in October 2013), you can now use `author__in` and `author__not_in` to pass an array of author IDs. Note that they both use two underscores after the word "author".

Here's how you would exclude author IDs 2, 3, and 4:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__not_in' => array( 2, 3, 4 ) ) );
```

[Here's a link to the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters)

[Here's a link to the developer docs.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it before, but it seems that you currently can't exclude multiple authors posts using WP_Query, I've updated the Codex to be less misleading.

Here is a way to exclude posts from multiple authors using the $wpdb class:

```
<?php

   $results = $wpdb->get_results(
   "Select * FROM $wpdb->posts
   WHERE post_type = 'post'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   AND post_author <> 2
   AND post_author <> 3", 
   OBJECT
   );// gets posts, that are published, and exclude posts written by authors 2 and 3

   foreach($results as $result)
   {
   echo "<h2>".$result->post_title."</h2>";
   }
```

?>

Comment: I put it in an array because i have other parameters need to be filled in. Besides, this query work for the positive author id, it suppose to work for the negative author id as well.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, because it completely short-circuits __all__ of the business logic and brains within WP_Query. You're much better using the 'posts_where' filter and appending to the existing WHERE clause (once you do the appropriate checking to be sure you're modifying only those queries you're interested in modifying). Your solution __works__, but is missing out on any of the "brains" that WordPress already provides. Sticking with filters is usually a much better bet.

Answer (score -1):

"UNTESTED" but could you do it this way?

```
 function filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

// If this is the blog posts index,
// and if this is the main query,

if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'author', -2,-3,4);
    }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

This is a function I picked up here for excluding categories. Not sure if it could be used to exclude by author but it is far better than writing a custom query if it works

Comment: I using the query in a plugin, so this method won't help. anyway thanks for the tips.

Comment: You can use `pre_get_posts` in a plug-in...

Comment: @Stephen Harris, I use the query for running at the background. How do I hook it when it is not depending on front end pages?

Comment: I'm not saying that you should use it for your specific purpose (I don't know what that is). I was just clarifying that `pre_get_posts` is available to plugins. I didn't want anyone to misunderstand your comment :)

Comment: Sadly, this will not work for a number of reasons 1. WP_Query->set() only takes 2 arguments - it will completely ignore the 3rd and 4th arguments; you probably meant `$query->set( 'author', '-2, -3, -4' );`, 2. however that will not work either based on a limitation on how the `author` query variable is currently being handled in core. Follow (and add your cc) to this bug/enhancement request: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16854